# Break String that came from Json

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I have a String that I got from a webserver which came in json format, but the string is huge with everything in it. I tried using the NSDICTIONARY but to no success. I was wondering what would be the best approach to break this string and add to different strings and eventually put it all in a class of strings. Thanks for the help! Here is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mym2webdesign.com/meiplay/paulsuckedabuffalo/artists.php"]];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; //Or async request
returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error=nil;

NSLog(@"HHHHHHHHHHHHHH"); //use this to know how far Im getting
NSLog(returnString); // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are

/*NSDictionary *results = [returnString JSONValue];
NSString *ID = [results objectForKey:@"ID"]; // for example
NSLog(@"ID Number: %@", ID);*/
```

Here is some of the log i get:

```
[{"ID":"1","name":"kevin","bio":"kevins bio"},{"ID":"1","name":"kevin","age":"20"},{"ID":"2","name":"Cesar","bio":"Cesar bio"},{"ID":"2","name":"Cesar","age":"19"},{"ID":"3", "name":"Katherine", "bio":"Katherines bio"},{"ID":"3", "name":"Katherine", "age":"22"}]
```

Comment: The outermost layer is an Array.  This can be easily seen by the enclosing `[]` characters.  The syntax of JSON blazingly simple and you need to learn it -- see http://www.json.org/ -- it'll take all of 10 minutes to learn, and then you won't have to beg for others to write your code for you.

Comment: Thanks thats going to help a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Its a `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`. So first you need to assign it to `NSArray` and then loop over it to get each individual `NSDictionary`. See below.

```
NSArray *results = [returnString JSONValue];
for(NSDictionary *record in results)
{
    NSLog(@"ID: %@", [record objectForKey:@"ID"]);
}
```

Comment: +1 Or, obviously, if using `NSJSONSerialization` it would be: `NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:&error];`, bypassing the `NSString` altogether.

Comment: that solved the problem, I knew it was something simple, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be better off just using `NSJSONSerialization` **if** your app is targeted for at or over iOS 5.0:

```
NSArray *JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:&error];
```

You might need to experiment with using NSArray vs. NSDictionary, etc., but this should be an overall simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    NSArray *results = [returnString JSONValue];
    for (int i=0; i<[results count];i++) {
       NSDictionary *DetailDictonary=[results objectAtIndex:i];
       NSString *strid=[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"ID"];
       NSString *strName=[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"name"]; 
       NSString *strBio=[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"bio"]; 

        // Or You can set it in Your ClassFile

       MyClass *classObj=[[MyClass alloc] init];
       classObj.strid=[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"ID"];
       classObj.strName=[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"name"]; 
       classObj.strBio=[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"bio"]; 

       [YourMainArray addObject:classObj]; //set YourClass to Array
       [classObj release];
    }
```

Comment: this would def be the way ill be doing it, thank you for providing me with an example!